# How to process remaining files in SFTP inbound adapter poll after an exception is thrown?

Tags: java, spring-integration, spring-integration-sftp

I have created an integration flow to read files from a SFTP server and process them. I realized that once there is an error with one of the files (an exception is thrown), the poll stops and any other file is not processed until the next poll. How can I avoid this, not marking the file as processed, and processing the remaining files in that poll?

My configuration is quite simple. I am using a non-transactional poller that is triggered every minute with `max-message-per-poll` of 1000. The `SftpStreamingInboundChannelAdapterSpec` has a `max-fetch-size` of 10 and uses a composite file list filter with a `SftpRegexPatternFileListFilter` and a `SftpPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter`.

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow sftpInboundFlow(JdbcMetadataStore jdbcMetadataStore, DataSourceTransactionManager dataSourceTransactionManager) {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(sftpStreamingInboundChannelAdapterSpec(jdbcMetadataStore), sourcePollingChannelAdapterSpec -> configureEndpoint(sourcePollingChannelAdapterSpec, dataSourceTransactionManager))
                .transform(new StreamTransformer())
                .channel("processingChannel")
                .get();
}

private SftpStreamingInboundChannelAdapterSpec sftpStreamingInboundChannelAdapterSpec(JdbcMetadataStore jdbcMetadataStore) {
    SftpStreamingInboundChannelAdapterSpec sftpStreamingInboundChannelAdapterSpec = Sftp.inboundStreamingAdapter(documentEnrollementSftpRemoteFileTemplate())
                .filter(fileListFilter(jdbcMetadataStore))
                .maxFetchSize(10)
                .remoteDirectory("/the-directory");
    SftpStreamingMessageSource sftpStreamingMessageSource = sftpStreamingInboundChannelAdapterSpec.get();
    sftpStreamingMessageSource.setFileInfoJson(false);

    return sftpStreamingInboundChannelAdapterSpec;
}

private void configureEndpoint(SourcePollingChannelAdapterSpec sourcePollingChannelAdapterSpec, DataSourceTransactionManager dataSourceTransactionManager) {
    PollerSpec pollerSpec = Pollers.cron(sftpProperties.getPollCronExpression())
                .maxMessagesPerPoll(1000);
    sourcePollingChannelAdapterSpec.autoStartup(true)
                .poller(pollerSpec);
}

@Bean
public CompositeFileListFilter<ChannelSftp.LsEntry> fileListFilter(JdbcMetadataStore jdbcMetadataStore) {
    String fileNameRegex = // get regex

    SftpRegexPatternFileListFilter sftpRegexPatternFileListFilter = new SftpRegexPatternFileListFilter(fileNameRegex);
    SftpPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter sftpPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter = new SftpPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter(jdbcMetadataStore, "");

    CompositeFileListFilter<ChannelSftp.LsEntry> compositeFileListFilter = new CompositeFileListFilter<>();
    compositeFileListFilter.addFilter(sftpRegexPatternFileListFilter);
    compositeFileListFilter.addFilter(sftpPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter);

    return compositeFileListFilter;
}
```

After reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19106450/5176576), I tried using a transactional poller as follows:

```
PollerSpec pollerSpec = Pollers.cron(sftpProperties.getPollCronExpression())
    .maxMessagesPerPoll(1000)
    .transactional(dataSourceTransactionManager);
```

but the result is that after the processing of a file fails, the poll stops, all processed messages are rolled back, and remaining messages are not processed until the next poll. What I understood from that answer was that every message would be processed in a separate transaction.

The only way I found to achieve this so far was to surround the processing code in a try/catch block catching all exceptions to avoid interrupting the poll. In the catch block I manually remove the `ChannelSftp.LsEntry` from the composite file list filter. For this I needed to set the property `fileInfoJson` to `false` in the `SftpStreamingMessageSource` provided by the `SftpStreamingInboundChannelAdapterSpec`.

I find this approach rather convoluted and with the downside that files that fail and are removed from the filter are immediately reprocessed afterwards and not in the following poll.I was hoping there is a more straightforward solution to my problem.

Comment: It would be better if you could show code, but your idea of catching the exception for a bad entry, dealing with it, and moving on, seems sound.  I don't see how this convoluted.

Comment: I have added some code with the configuration. I would like to avoid, if possible, having to manually remove the files from the filter. I was expecting that making the poller transactional would do that for me. But it seems that all messages are rolled back, not only the one that caused the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution with the *try...catch* is the way to go. This is really the fact that exception thrown from the process is bubbled into the poller and it stops the current cycle around `maxMessagesPerPoll`:

```
private Runnable createPoller() {
    return () ->
            this.taskExecutor.execute(() -> {
                int count = 0;
                while (this.initialized && (this.maxMessagesPerPoll <= 0 || count < this.maxMessagesPerPoll)) {
                    if (pollForMessage() == null) {
                        break;
                    }
                    count++;
                }
            });
}
```

Where that `pollForMessage()` is like this:

```
private Message<?> pollForMessage() {
    try {
        return this.pollingTask.call();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        if (e instanceof MessagingException) {
            throw (MessagingException) e;
        }
        else {
            Message<?> failedMessage = null;
            if (this.transactionSynchronizationFactory != null) {
                Object resource = TransactionSynchronizationManager.getResource(getResourceToBind());
                if (resource instanceof IntegrationResourceHolder) {
                    failedMessage = ((IntegrationResourceHolder) resource).getMessage();
                }
            }
            throw new MessagingException(failedMessage, e); // NOSONAR (null failedMessage)
        }
    }
    finally {
        if (this.transactionSynchronizationFactory != null) {
            Object resource = getResourceToBind();
            if (TransactionSynchronizationManager.hasResource(resource)) {
                TransactionSynchronizationManager.unbindResource(resource);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Anyway there is still a way to isolate one message from others in the single polling cycle. For this purpose you need to take a look into the *Request Handler Advice Chain* and investigate a solution with the `ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice`: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/#message-handler-advice-chain

So, you add this into your handler endpoint downstream and catch exceptions over there and do some specific error handling not re-throwing exceptions to poller.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! I already tried using an advice for the method annotated with `@ServiceActivator`, which I think is more or less equivalent to what you mention. Still, if I want to process the same file again on a subsequent poll, I need to manually remove it from the file list filter, right? But if I do this, then the file is immediately reprocessed until `max-message-per-poll` messages have been processed (potentially 999 times). Is there a way to process the file only once per poll?

Comment: Why should you remove it from there? Why don't try with a *retry advice*  on that `@ServiceActivator`? It fully sounds like you want to have a retry anyway, so why deffer that to the poller if you have a file already in hands and can retry over it in the only particular place like that `@ServiceActivator`.

Comment: My idea was to never mark a file as processed if an unexpected error occurs even after some retries, hoping that whatever transient error occurred would be "fixed" by the next poll(s). Otherwise, I do not see how I can reprocess the file later on.

Comment: You can use a `Delayer` to really delay this file for remove from the filter. So, it won't appear again in the current polling cycle.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, the `Delayer` did the trick. However, it is a pitty I cannot persist the delayed message in the message store since it has an non-serializable LsEntry as header. I guess I would need my own file list filters for that...